# Multiple buttons that generate with total

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to make multiple buttons when clicked it generates a textview. I used Mattia for help :) Have I done it right? Also the counter is the total, currently in the code the counter keep adding one (because its counter++) but if I change it to counter+10 it wont work :( Can some one help with that.

the code

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

int counter = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_button);
    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.test2);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            counter++;

            TextView textView = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
            textView.setText("You have added noodles and your total is" + counter);
            textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
            textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"));

            linearLayout.addView(textView);
        }
    });
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            counter++;

            TextView textView = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
            textView.setText("you have added hotdog and your total is " + counter);
            textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
            textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"));

            linearLayout.addView(textView);
        }
    });
}
```

and the main file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/add_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add TextView" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/test2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add TextView" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />
```

Comment: counter+10? i think you are looking for counter+=10

Comment: An advice ,According to your code you are adding views to layout when a user clicks a button, you are not able to view all the views as u haven't using a scrollView

Answer (score 1):

Try like this, If I understood your question right it should work.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    int counter = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_button);
        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.test2);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                counter+= 10;

                TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
                textView.setText("You have added noodles and your total is" + counter);
                textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
                textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"));


            }
        });
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                counter+=10;

                TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
                textView.setText("you have added hotdog and your total is " + counter);
                textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
                textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"));


            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to type counter+=10; (notice the '+', it is equivalent to saying counter = counter+10;)

counter+10; doesn't save the increment.